# In Gwt, using <table> inside HTMLPanel to design layout is good or not good?

Tags: gwt

Many web designers are strongly against using table to design layout due to they think table for tabular data not for holding the object.

I feel table is so easy to understand, easy to use, well-structured. I don't like Div cos it's really hard to use & hard to understand as well.

But in the Gwt context, I heard someone with 12K reputation suggest to use `<Table>` inside `HTMLPanel` to control layout since it 's quite easy to use & more flexible then if we use Gwt Layout widgets such as FlowLayout, LayoutPanel...

UiBinder file:
      more row + colums here to design layout

So In Gwt, using `<table>` inside HTMLPanel to design layout is good or not good?

Comment: Your question shouldn't be opinion-based. Try to come up with concrete examples if possible.

Comment: i remember a person with 12K reputation suggested to use table inside HTMLPanel & i couldn't find that link. That is why i wants to ask this question to see how Gwt specialists think about it

Comment: imho, table is good to display tabular data and nothing else. If you want a datagrid, use table. For all other needs, use div + CSS. Tip : If you really need table-like display, use CSS properties `display:table`, `display:table-row`, `display:table-cell`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think correct answer is to use Div cos using table will cause some quirks in other older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 12k rep but here is what we do.
Our designer made us use [gwt-bootstrap](http://gwtbootstrap.github.io/) which offers the same functionalities for scaffolding as Twitter-Boostrap does.

I never had to use layout widget, and I thank him for that.

Answer (score 0):

The  layout is simple, but isn't efficient for the browser, the browser must wait to have and parse all the table html before begin to render the table.(Now modern browser try to render before this). The problem comes when the there are many table in nested table. Most of gwt panel use table, and a layout build in GWT with VerticalPanel, HorizontalPanel, GridPanel, FlexPanel, DisclosurePanel, TabPanel will use many nested table, and will be very hard for the browser for render.
The use of a HtmlPanel and one table will be better than many nested table.